# Hyperref causing "missing number" error with tikzpicture

Tags: errors, hyperref, compilation-error

When attempting to draw the following diagram, latex throws an error if the hyperref library is installed.

Any idea why?

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds}

%**%CAUSES ERROR WHEN IMPORTED%**

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=13mm,y=9mm]
  % some styles
  \tikzset{
    box/.style={
      minimum height=5mm,
      inner sep=.7mm,
      outer sep=0mm,
      text width=10mm,
      text centered,
      font=\small\bfseries\sffamily,
      text=#1!50!black,
      draw=#1,
      line width=.25mm,
      rotate=0,
    },
    link/.style={-latex,line width=.3mm},
    plus/.style={,},
  }
  % Pascal's triangle
  % row #0 => value is 1
  \node (p-0-0) at (0,0) {1};
  \foreach \row in {1,...,8} {
     % col #0 =&gt; value is 1
    \node (p-\row-0) at (-\row/2,-\row) {1};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\value}{1};
    \foreach \col in {1,...,\row} {
      % iterative formula : val = precval * (row-col+1)/col
      % (+ 0.5 to bypass rounding errors)
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\value}{\value*((\row-\col+1)/\col)+0.5};
      \global\let\value=\value
      % position of each value
      \coordinate (pos) at (-\row/2+\col,-\row);
      % odd color for odd value and even color for even value
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rest}{mod(\value,2)}
      \ifnum \rest=0
        \node (p-\row-\col) at (pos) {\value};
      \else
        \node (p-\row-\col) at (pos) {\value};
      \fi
      % for arrows and plus sign
      \ifnum \col<\row
        \node[plus,above=0mm of p-\row-\col]{+};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prow}{\row-1}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\pcol}{\col-1}
        \draw[link] (p-\prow-\pcol) -- (p-\row-\col);
        \draw[link] ( p-\prow-\col) -- (p-\row-\col);
      \fi
    }
  }
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    % filling and drawing with the same color to enlarge background
    \path[draw=white,line width=5mm,rounded corners=2.5mm]
    (  p-0-0.north west) -- (  p-0-0.north east) --
    (p-8-8.north east) -- (p-8-8.south east) --
    ( p-8-0.south west) -- ( p-8-0.north west) --
    cycle;
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it is a very bad idea to redefine \value, even more if you do it  globally.

Answer (score 2):

Rename `\value` to something else:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds}

%**%CAUSES ERROR WHEN IMPORTED%**

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=13mm,y=9mm]
  % some styles
  \tikzset{
    box/.style={
      minimum height=5mm,
      inner sep=.7mm,
      outer sep=0mm,
      text width=10mm,
      text centered,
      font=\small\bfseries\sffamily,
      text=#1!50!black,
      draw=#1,
      line width=.25mm,
      rotate=0,
    },
    link/.style={-latex,line width=.3mm},
    plus/.style={,},
  }
  % Pascal's triangle
  % row #0 => value is 1
  \node (p-0-0) at (0,0) {1};
  \foreach \row in {1,...,8} {
     % col #0 =&gt; value is 1
    \node (p-\row-0) at (-\row/2,-\row) {1};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myvalue}{1};
    \foreach \col in {1,...,\row} {
      % iterative formula : val = precval * (row-col+1)/col
      % (+ 0.5 to bypass rounding errors)
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myvalue}{\myvalue*((\row-\col+1)/\col)+0.5};
      \global\let\myvalue=\myvalue
      % position of each value
      \coordinate (pos) at (-\row/2+\col,-\row);
      % odd color for odd value and even color for even value
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rest}{mod(\myvalue,2)}
      \ifnum \rest=0
        \node (p-\row-\col) at (pos) {\myvalue};
      \else
        \node (p-\row-\col) at (pos) {\myvalue};
      \fi
      % for arrows and plus sign
      \ifnum \col<\row
        \node[plus,above=0mm of p-\row-\col]{+};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prow}{\row-1}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\pcol}{\col-1}
        \draw[link] (p-\prow-\pcol) -- (p-\row-\col);
        \draw[link] ( p-\prow-\col) -- (p-\row-\col);
      \fi
    }
  }
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    % filling and drawing with the same color to enlarge background
    \path[draw=white,line width=5mm,rounded corners=2.5mm]
    (  p-0-0.north west) -- (  p-0-0.north east) --
    (p-8-8.north east) -- (p-8-8.south east) --
    ( p-8-0.south west) -- ( p-8-0.north west) --
    cycle;
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]